# Do the format strings for printf et al behave differently on Borland C and in GCC?

Tags: gcc, printf, borland-c

I am working on porting an old codebase from Borland C to C99. I have come across the following function, which looks like it should copy zero bytes into a buffer.

```
sprintf(tx_tcp_buf,"%0s%0s%0s%0s%0s%0s",strHeader, ccSTX, drValidity, ccUS, "Y",ccETX);
```

The declaration of `tx_tcp_buf` is `static BYTE tx_tcp_buf[150] = {0};`.

All of `strHeader`, `ccSTX`, `drValidity`, `ccUS`, and `ccETX` are of type `char *`.

What's bugging me is the length specifier in the format string. It is my first time of encountering a length specifier of zero, for a string. Here, we've got `%0s` which from what I read should copy zero bytes. (So what is the above call to `sprintf` even doing?)

I don't have a copy of Borland C, but I've tried the following program in GCC:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
     char buf[256];
     char * hello = "Hello, World!\n";
     printf(buf, "%0s", hello);
     printf("\"%s\"\n",buf);
}
```

It's output is

```
"Hello, World!
"
```

Evidently the `%0s` isn't doing much that `%s` wouldn't do. But with `-pedantic -Wall -std=c99`, I get a warning, which specifically mentions some `gnu_printf` format:

```
warning: '0' flag used with '%s' gnu_printf format [-Wformat=]
       sprintf(tx_tcp_buf,"%0s%0s%0s%0s%0s%0s",strHeader,ccSTX,drStatus,ccUS,"I",ccETX);
```

Do different compilers have different behaviours here? I'm especially interested in Borland C, and GCC. But it would be good to know about others.

Comment: http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/borland/borland_C++/Borland_C++_Version_3.1_Library_Reference_1992.pdf page ~400. I only see `0n` as the relevant `Width specifier` but nothing much more - looks like the same as in C. But the `0` is not even in `Flag characters` on page 401. And I have trouble distinguishing `0` from `O`.

Comment: "*which from what I read should copy zero bytes*" - where did you read that from? The `0` in `%0s` is not a length specifier at all, it is a flag to specify that the output should be left-padded with leading 0s instead of spaces, if a length were specified. Except in this case, that flag has no effect for `%s`, so it gets ignored.  See GCC's [Formatted Output](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Formatted-Output.html) documentation, and CppReference's [printf() documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)